# Salts: Hashed or plain text?

Tags: php, database, hash

I want to store a (random) salt next to the password in the database. Now, the question is:

Should I store it hashed or in plain text? Is there any difference (more security, faster?)? An how much effort should I put in creating a random string?

Sample code:

```php
    //Creating random salt
    $saltchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~";

    $salt = uniqid(rand(), true).str_shuffle($saltchars);
    // Or should the salt be hashed (md5 or sha512 for more security)
    // $salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(rand(), true).$staticsalt.str_shuffle($saltchars));
    //Create user (with salt & pepper)
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO users (user, password, salt) VALUES('$id','".hash('sha512', $staticsalt.$accesskey.$salt)."','".$salt."');"; 
    $sqlresult = mysql_query($sqlquery);
```

for the record: the login-script

```
    $sqlquery = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE user='$id';"; 
    $sqlresult = mysql_query($sqlquery); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($sqlresult) == 1) { 

    $salt = (mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult));

//Check if the password is correct
    $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$id' AND password='".hash('sha512', $staticsalt.$accesskey.$salt[0])."'";
    $sqlresult = mysql_query($sqlquery);
    unset($accesskey, $salt);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($sqlresult) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($sqlresult) == 1) 
        {echo 'Login successfull';}
        else {die('Error: wrong user ID/password');}
    }
   }
```

I know that there are many, probably too many, websites out there discussing the pros & cons of a salt. But nobody answers if the salt should be encrypt or not - and nobody shows how to code a login script with random (!) salts (saved in the database as I did).

So as a php beginner I have no idea if this code is secure or not? Or if there are any tricks to make it faster or more streamlined... Thanks!

Comment: If the salt is truly random, and you store it encrypted, how do you intend to decrypt it?

Comment: As there is no way to encrypt it, the login script would use the hashed salt, hash it again (now with: $staticsalt.$password.$salt) and compare it with the stored "password"

Comment: @Nyoman: If you use the hashed salt when checking the password, then you have accomplished nothing by hashing it. As you are using the salt in the way that it's stored, it's actually stored in plain text.

Comment: the only advantage I see using a hashed salt is that it would be longer, but as it is stored as plain text this is not a real advantage (as you or Alexander Gessler said)...

Comment: @Nyoman: then you aren't hashing the salt, the salt is the output of the hashing function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need the salt to compute a password hash in the login script, you can't just store the hash of the salt as this would be an irreversible operation, i.e. the original salt would be lost.

So I'm presuming you're asking whether hashing the original salt obtained from picking a random string yields a better salt. In this case the use of a hashing function has nothing to do with 'hashing', it would just be a way to generate a longer, seemingly more random sequence. This makes absolutely no sense, however, as the hashed salt will still need to be stored in the database - in plaintext if you will!

Comment: To elaborate: hashing a random string doesn't make it any more random. With a perfect hashing function, you'd get exactly the same amount of randomness; with a weaker hash, you'll reduce the randomness of your salt. Just create a sufficiently long random string with a random number generator that isn't utterly broken (which means, avoid `rand()`).

Comment: @tdammers okay, I changed the random number generator to mt_rand() - I know it's not perfect but at least it seems to give better random numbers...

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter. You can assume the salt is public information, since the attack the salt helps protect against -- rainbow-table assisted dictionary attacks -- isn't made any easier if the salt is known by the attacker. You should ask yourself why you think it's a good idea to encrypt the salt in the first place.

Also, you should read this:

- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Funny that sluggishness is a feature.

Comment: okay, if bcrypt is "THE ONLY FUTURE-PROOF hash algorithm" why is there no simple implementation in php core?

Comment: @Nyoman - There are PHP implementations. The page above links to one.

Comment: Couldn't the attacker create a rainbow table for the known salt and then we would be back to stage 1 on using salt? (Or I misunderstood something?)

Comment: @DADi590 Yes, they could, but doing so might be prohibitive. Modern computers are fast enough to generate a table for some kinds of hash functions (and sufficiently weak password parameters) on time scales that make it worth it, so the typical defense is to use an iterated hash function that's *deliberately slow*, so that producing a table is impossible within your lifetime.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand why salts can be stored as plain-text in dbs? What if the attacker gets the control of DB and then uses one of the salts in the dbs and incorporates his rainbow table with this salt and then performs the rainbow-attacks? I guess, creating a whole new rainbow table for each salt just makes the method too inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody talks about the salt being hashed because the salt *can't* be hashed.  If it's not obvious why - and if you truly "have no idea if this code is secure or not" - *please* use somebody else's authentication system instead of creating your own, because it is very, very easy to leave gaping security holes if you don't know what you are doing.

Edit:

A hash is one-way.  You put data in.  You don't take data out.  That's what it's for.  If you put the salt in, you can't get it out.  If you can't get it out, you can't add it to the password the user supplies.  If you can't do that, you can't use it as a salt.

Comment: I think your answer mostly answers nothing. If I were you, I would move the suggestion to use someone else's authentication system to a comment and explain your statements instead of saying it should be obvious.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain.  If you know what salts and hashes are, then this *is* obvious.  If you don't, why are you trying to code them?  As for the suggestion to use somebody else's system - if somebody asked me how to shoot themselves in the foot, I wouldn't tell them to point a gun at their foot and pull the trigger, I'd tell them they really don't want to do that.

Comment: I would still comment that they should use someone else's system rather than embarrass them, and not post any answer. See Alexander Gessler's answer, who made a better point out of the salt thing.

Comment: There's nothing embarrassing about not being an expert in authentication systems - I already said it is *easy* to get wrong.  Using somebody else's system is not a comment, it *is* the answer.  There is no other responsible answer to give.

Comment: okay if using somebody else's system is the answer, would you mind to show an example for a good authentication systems (in php)?

Comment: I don't work with PHP these days, but you are probably best off using one of the better-known framework's authentication systems.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the salt is so that someone can't use the same rainbow tables for cracking all the passwords. To create a new rainbow table for each password just makes the method too inefficient. You don't have to hide the salt, hiding it doesn't increase the security.

As the salt isn't a cryptographic key, and it doesn't have to be hidden, you don't have to be very elaborate when creating them. Just use a regular random generator to pick some random characters.

Besides, you can't hash the salt anyway, because then you can't use it to check the passwords when someone want to log in.